# Check if the NSTextView is empty in OSX

Tags: macos, cocoa, nstextview

I am trying to display message if the NSTextView is empty(The user hasn't entered anything in the textView) but couldnt find an appropriate built in method.In case of NSTextFiled it was simple.

```
if(countElements(emailTextField.stringValue) == 0)
```

Is there a substitute for NSTextView in mac

Comment: Are you having problems with the obtaining of the contents of the textview, or with the validation of the contents?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get access to the `NSTextStorage` object held by the `NSTextView`, and use the (read-only) `length` property to count the elements in the storage object's underlying `string` property:

```
// Mark: NSTextViewDelegate implementation

func textDidChange(notification: NSNotification) {

    if let textView = notification.object as? NSTextView {
        if let storage = textView.textStorage {
            if storage.length == 0 {
                // text-view is empty
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If you look at the `NSTextStorage` class reference you'll see that it is in fact just an `NSAttributedString` subclass. An `NSAttributedString` has a `string` property, and a `length` property - it's the `length` property that we're using to determine if the string is 'empty'.